# Android | Kotlin: How do I automatically change the text color based on device theme?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, colors

I get that this question has probably been asked many times but in this specific situation I'm using gradients for my background so I can't base on solid background color. How do you get the theme (light/dark mode) on the device and change the text color accordingly? For instance, my Emulator uses light mode so the text looks fine but when switching to my actual device (using dark mode), the text still stays the same color (black) while the background changes from light to dark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would create a new values folder `values-night` where you would create a whole new theme for night and your regular `values` folder would be your light theme.

Set the theme name as the same as your theme you have in your values folder and it will switch automatically

Comment: so everytime I update or add something I would have to update the other one right?

Comment: if its something that needs to be different in both modes yes

Comment: Following @tyczj response, you can inherit your app theme from `Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight` or `Theme.AppCompat.DayNight`. All day-night variants provide a suitable base that should work out of the box for most scenarios.

Comment: oh, I didn't think of that, my question was solved way faster than expected. Thank you all ;)

Comment: Working example: https://github.com/ashutoshgngwr/noice/blob/main/app/src/main/res/values/styles.xml